# span OpenVPN network (from one VPC) to another VPC

Tags: openvpn, aws

Here is the scenario:

1. VPC1 has OpenVPN: OpenVPN is connected to home network.
2. EC2 instances in VPC2 need to connect to home network via OpenVPN in VPC1.
3. EC2 instances in VPC3 need to connect to home network via OpenVPN in VPC1.

Is this possible/a good practice?

Comment: Routing between OpenVPN networks is possible AFAIK (I never tried), but not trivial (you need special configurations). Consider using an VPN alternative, e.g. [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org), where routing just works as usual.

Comment: @dirkt agree. I was hoping to do the same with VPC peering and VPC inter-region peering. but was not sure if I can span the home network across VPC2 and VPC3 from VPC1 via route tables.